# Using jQuery Mobile Pagecreate to Access jQuery Function on Page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am having difficulty understanding how to use jQuery Mobile's pagecreate to load some jQuery functions into a page. Any time a page is loaded (whether it is visited directly or clicked to), I would like to have access to the swipeleft function below...

This functions properly if I visit the page directly, but as soon as I try navigating back to it (i.e. get there through href tags) it stops working. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#listitem').live('pagecreate',function(event){
$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 130;
$("#listitem").swipeleft(function() {
    $('#settings_click').click();
});
});
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="listitem">
<?php //content in here ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/QFuGK/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#listitem', function(event){       
    $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 130;        
    $(document).off('swipeleft').on('swipeleft', '#listitem', function(){     
        $('#settings_click').trigger('click');
    });        

    $(document).off('click').on('click', '#settings_click', function(){  
        alert('Button clicked');
    });         
});
```

You should change your pagecreate with a pagebeforeshow event.

To test this code, inside a working example go to the another page and come back. Swipe event will trigger normally.

One more thing, .off( method is used to remove event before applying it again, without it swipeleft event would be bound again and again when you return back to the page.